# IS the following series convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am trying to study the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^k (\log n)^k}{n^2} $$

Where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

What test would work in this case?

Comment: Note that the logarithm $\log n$ grows slower than any positive power of $n$. So you can apply p-series test. Also the exact value of the series is $\zeta^{(k)}(2)$.

Comment: IS there a closed form for $\zeta^{(k)}(2) $ ?

Comment: I don't think so. We may have one for $k=1$ in view of the [*Glaisher-Kinkelin constant*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher–Kinkelin_constant) together with the functional equation for the Riemann zeta function. This is a disguise, however, since the derivative is just absorbed into that magical constant.

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: $\zeta^{(k)}(2)\simeq(-1)^kk!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's interesting expand the Sangchul Lee comment and see that $$\frac{d\zeta}{ds}\left(s\right)=\frac{d}{ds}\left(\sum_{n\geq1}n^{-s}\right)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{d}{ds}\left(n^{-s}\right)=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\log\left(n\right)}{n^{s}}$$ and so on.